# Reactjs - Redirect user until task is completed

Tags: reactjs, redirect, flask

After working with Flask and Jinja2 server-side templating, I've decided to move my template rendering to Frontend using React. At this stage I' trying to wrap my mind around redirecting.

---

In the following example, I have someone clicking on a link to a given endpoint, but this requires a task being completed beforehand.

> *Backend*

**Menus.html**

```
<li><a href="{{ url_for('cooking') }}";>Pasta</a>
```

When user clicks the link to 'pasta', I render some animation, and when task is done, user gets redirected to desired endpoint, like so:

**Cooking.html**

```
<div class="dish"></div>
<p class="txt">Cooking your pasta...</p>

<script> window.location.replace('/pasta');
</script>
```

---

> *Frontend*

Now I'm trying to reproduce this using React. So far I have:

In (simplified) **Menus.jsx**:

```
   import Cooking from './Cooking.jsx';

   render(){
        return (
          <div>
           <Cooking/>
          </div>
        );       
      }
 }
```

And in **Cooking.jsx**:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Cooking = (props) => (
     <div>
       <Link to="/cooking">Pasta</Link>
     </div>
  )
export default Cooking;
```

No, how do I similarly redirect(route) user to `/pasta` after `/cooking` is done?

Comment: Just animated CSS happening in cooking component. You can answer if you wish

Comment: Show your Routes. It is really confusing that you have `Link` in `Cooking` component and you want to redirect to same component? How the clicking on `Pasta` link know the cooking is completed?

Comment: @ravibagul91 I don’t want to redirect to the same component, but to a different route (and component), /pasta, after a task is completed at the background and an animation is triggered at client . This setup works at backend and it’s not confusing at all. Cooking acts as a transition component, that’s all. Maybe it should not even be a component, just a function, I don’t know.

Comment: <Link to="/cooking">Pasta</Link> this is confusing. It saying that on the click of Pasta you want to go to `Cooking` component.

Comment: No. It sates that if a user clicks there he will get to /pasta at the end, but not right away. User does not need to know the code

Comment: Anyway, I don’t have the answer, that’s the best I could do to convey what I wish to achieve. I’m new to React sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.props.history.push('/pasta')` or `this.props.history.replace('/pasta')` and since it's just simple animation you can add a setTimeout() just to add a delay before redirecting.

> You can read more at
>   https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history

Comment: could you elaborate a bit further on your answer using my code above? I did not get precisely how this could be achieved.

Comment: May I know how long does the cooking last? Or is it just a loading screen and may not load fully.

Comment: From 5 to 10 seconds, and it loads fully from the start